# How to deploy an expressJS application from slack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-deployment, slack

Recently i came to know about that we can deploy our nodeJS applications just by entering a command in slack. I am pretty much confused about this and don't know how to do that. I found a blog which does what i want but there isn't technical details in that blog.

https://tech-blog.serenytics.com/deploy-your-saas-with-a-slack-bot-f6d1fc764658#.yzk9ff982

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-slack-bot-with-node-js-and-chuck-norris-super-powers) which shows step-wise how to create a slack bot using node.

The tutorial uses [slackbots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slackbots) npm package which interfaces with Slack's realtime messaging API using websockets and so you don't strictly need express. But if you want, you can easily integrate with an express based application.

As to the part where actual deployment orchestration is concerned, it will depend on how your application is deployed. If you are using docker then a good option is using [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) node module to create and start containers.

Comment: i am using dokku to deploy on digitalocean server

Comment: This is interesting, but if your application gets deployed automatically through git push webhooks, why do you need slack integration ? 
In any case, you can trigger the cli commands [here](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/application-deployment/) by [spawning a child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) from node.

Comment: Actually the problem is, i have a dist/ folder in which i have code to deploy on dokku.. but i also have a repo on github on which i dont have to push dist/ because it will automatically create whenever i use `gulp` command.  so whenever i have to push code on dokku, i have to change .gitignore file.. so i dont know how to resolve this problem .. i am just serching all over the internet. One person said i have to build a bot. so thats why i am confused right now. @lorefnon

Comment: but i think , what u have suggested the cli commands... i think they can be used..